# Create div between n number of element

Tags: jquery

Can any one help me out like how to wrap a div between two heading. im not able to add any class/Id for element.

for example :

```
<h1>heading</h1>
<p>sample content</p>
<p>sample content</p>
<p>sample content</p>
<h3>Heading</h3>
```

and i need in the below format

```
<h1>heading</h1>
<div>
<p>sample content</p>
<p>sample content</p>
<p>sample content</p>
</div>
<h3>Heading</h3>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [**nextUntil**](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/) and [**wrapAll**](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

```js
$('h1').nextUntil('h3').wrapAll('<div class="wrapped"></div>');
```

```css
.wrapped {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>heading</h1>
<p>sample content</p>
<p>sample content</p>
<p>sample content</p>
<h3>Heading</h3>
```

Comment: Should be `.wrapAll()`

Comment: @Andreas, I see, it was wrapping each p element separately. Thanks for the tip! :-)